# Circuitikz: changing switches orientation

Tags: circuitikz

In `circuitikz`, all the switches go from left to right.  There is a mirror option that goes from left to right but opens on the bottom.

I want the switch to go from right to left with a top opening.  How can I do this?

Attached is a screen shot from the manual that has MWE and image of what is currently available.

All that is needed is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest circutikz-version 0.7 includes a new option "invert", which changes the drawing direction.
With the combination of the options invert and mirror, all possible views should be reachable.

Answer (score 2):

Would this do what you want?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

 \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (2,0) to[ospst=T, mirror] (0,0);
 \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes and no.  No because I am running my circuit in the other direction which would flip the voltage source upside down and there is no mirror for option for that.  That is, I need it to move from right to left in the code.

Comment: Can you provide a picture for that, it can be in paint or so, just to have a better understanding of what you want

Comment: In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172089/circuitikz-arrows-on-the-path-and-changing-directions-of-arrow-with-variable-re), you will see a complete circuit I have made in the question.  If we re-route the direction of movement, the american voltage source would be negative on top.  Changing movement can mess with other pieces.